# what is the quickest way to delete duplicate rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, delete, duplication

I need to delete duplicate rows from a large table.
what is the best way to achieve that?

currently I use this algorithm:

```
declare @t table ([key] int  )

insert into @t select 1
insert into @t select 1
insert into @t select 1
insert into @t select 2
insert into @t select 2
insert into @t select 3
insert into @t select 4
insert into @t select 4
insert into @t select 4
insert into @t select 4
insert into @t select 4
insert into @t select 5
insert into @t select 5
insert into @t select 5
insert into @t select 5
insert into @t select 5
insert into @t select 6
insert into @t select 6
insert into @t select 6
insert into @t select 7
insert into @t select 7
insert into @t select 8
insert into @t select 8
insert into @t select 9
insert into @t select 9
insert into @t select 9
insert into @t select 9
insert into @t select 9


select * from @t

; with cte as (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by [Key] order by [Key]) as Picker
    from @t
    )
delete cte 
where Picker > 1

select * from @t
```

when I run it on my system:

```
;WITH Customer AS
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountCode ORDER BY AccountCode ) AS [Version]
    FROM Stage.Customer
    )
    DELETE
    FROM    Customer
    WHERE   [Version] <> 1
```

[image]

I found that <> 1 is better than > 1.

I could create this index, currently not present:

```
USE [BodenDWH]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [Stage].[Customer] ([AccountCode])
INCLUDE ([ID])
GO
```

[image]

Is there any other way to get this done?

On this occasion this table is not big - about 500,000 records on the live system.

the delete is part of a SSIS package, it runs daily and deletes about 10-15 records a day.

there are problems in the way the data is structured, I just need one AccountCode for each customer but there could be duplicates and if they are not removed, they break the package on a later stage.

It was not me who developed the package, and my scope is not to re-design anything.

I am just after the best way to get rid of the duplicates, in the quickest possible way, without having to refer to index creation, or anything, just the T-SQL code.

Comment: Just trying to understand .. Do you have dupes in `AccountCode` that you want to get rid of ? And how many records are you trying to delete ?

Comment: yes, sometimes there are dupes in AccountCode, they generally are more than 10 and less than 50 but there are days, there are no dupes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the table is small and the number of rows you are deleting is small, then use

```
;WITH Customer AS
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountCode ORDER BY (select null) ) AS [Version]
    FROM dbo.Customer
    )
    DELETE
    FROM    Customer
    WHERE   [Version] > 1;
```

Note: In above query you are using an arbitrary ordering in the window order clause `ORDER BY (select null)` *(learned it from [Itzik Ben-Gan's T-SQL Querying book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735685045) and @AaronBertrand cited that above as well)*.

If the table is large (e.g. 5M records) then deleting in [small number of rows or chunks](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) will help not bloat transaction log and will prevent [lock escalation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx).

> A lock escalation will occur if and only if a Transact-SQL statement has acquired at least 5000 locks on a single reference of a table.

```
while 1=1
begin
WITH Customer AS
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountCode ORDER BY (select null) ) AS [Version]
    FROM dbo.Customer
    )
    DELETE top(4000) -- choose a lower batch size than 5000 to prevent lock escalation 
    FROM    Customer
    WHERE   [Version] > 1

    if @@ROWCOUNT < 4000
    BREAK ;

end
```